# How to store collection of values as attributes in DynamoDB table?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a structure with collection of items inside that need to stored in DynamoDB table. Using current implementation `items` are stored as JSON but I would like to have them as unique attributes in table. Is it possible using `spring-data-dynamodb` library?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "orders")
public class Order {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private long userId;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private List<Item> items;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Item {
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String name;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String value;
}
```

Expected result:

```
Table: orders
| id | userId | item_name1  | item_name2  | item_name3  |
| s2 | 234    | item_value1 | item_value1 | item_value3 |
```

Comment: When you say "unique attributes in table" I assume you mean as a top level field with its name set to the value of `name`, and its value set to the value of `value`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think you're going to have to do it at a lower level. The library you are using is a convenience library to simplify basic cases. You're wanting to do something that doesn't fall into that.

Comment: It's really sad :(
Using lower level it can be done very easy, I thought there is a way to store it using library.

Comment: The lower level SDK isn't hard to use. I am a .Net person, but the SDKs are basically the same. I rarely use the higher level library anymore (largely because I found a bug a couple years ago that was crushing my app).

Comment: So it's time to migrate my code, I am grateful to you, Jason!